# How do i copy N images from server to my local machine using rsync?

Tags: ubuntu, unix, rsync, scp

I want to copy n images from my server to local machine 
i hve tried the command :

```
rsync -P <Source>(.om[1,100]) <localmachine>
```

but using this is not working

Comment: Do the remote files end .om1, .om2, .om3, etc ?

Comment: No its a jpeg file containing more than 100 images i just want to transfer a 100 files

Answer (score 2):

You could just put the files in a directory and upload the whole directory. If you don't want to do that, try this command:

```
rsync -P user@server:'/path/imagefilename.om{1..100}' destination-dir/
```

Comment: All the images in the directory has different file names and all are jpg files.

Comment: Are the image filenames random? Or do you have image1.jpg, image2.jpg etc. up to image100.jpg?
Do you just want to download 100 images from a folder with more than a 100 images but you do not care which of those images you download as long as you download exactly 100? Sorry for all the questions but your original question is confusing to me.

Comment: Yes all the image names are random . I want to download the first 100 images from a folder with more than 100 images.

Comment: Ok, then my answer does not help you. I wanted to downvote it but I'm not allowed to do that. But I don't want to delete it since it might help somebody else who has filenames with sequential numbers in them. Guess it's best if you try Smock or Geralds solutions if you have a real shell on the remote machine. I don't know of a better solution, sorry.

Comment: Thankyou for your help

Answer (score 2):

rsync has no way of listing and restricting to files on the remote server. So you have to build a list of files beforehand.  You can do that, for example, using `find` and `head`:

```
find /path/to/dir -type f |head -n 100'
```

will return the first 100 files found.

`rsync` has the parameter `--files-from`, which allows you to read the list of files to copy from a file. It can even read that list [from the remote server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16647476/how-to-rsync-only-a-specific-list-of-files/30176688#30176688). So, you could write that list of files into a file, and provide it to rsync.

But you can actually do all that with a single command:

```
ssh source 'find /path/to/dir -type f |head -n 100' | rsync --files-from - source:/ /path/to/local/dir
```

This will connect with ssh to the server `source` and return the first 100 files from the search result. This result is then piped into rsync. Using `-` as the value for the parameter `--files-from` tells rsync to read that 'file' from stdin instead of an actual file. Then you provide the source and the target as usual.

Comment: Provided ssh is on the remote machine (I'm assuming they're both *nix, and there's no reason to think it won't be), this is the best answer +1

Answer (score 0):

> i just want to transfer a 100 files

To transfer 100 files that are not a sequence set you can use this:

```
rsync -P `ls source-dir/ -U | head -100` destination-dir/
```

There's no option of rsync (that I can find) that just transfers 100 and stops

Instead you need to find a way to select 100 files to pass to rsync as a list

*If the source folder is a remote one, you may have to mount it (auto-fs maybe)*

```
rsync -P `ls /mnt/source-dir/ -U | head -100` destination-dir/
```

Comment: The source dir in the OP is on a different server.

Comment: i think you could try 
    ` rsync -P `ls source:mounted-source-dir/ -U | head -100` destination-dir/ `
(cant add the upper marks for the commands

Comment: try typing `\\`` to get a `\``

Comment: @djdomi I'm not sure `ls source:folder/` for a remote folder would work - have you got any links that might help shed light on how to use ls to list a remote folder? I'll add it to the answer if you can.